# match pattern for startswith

Tags: c#, regex

I want to do a Regex Match in c# to check whether a string starts with part of pattern.
Say if the pattern is "ABC...GHI" then valid strings can be in the format "A","AB","ABCDEF","ABCXYXGHI"

This is a sample code. What exactly regex has to be in the pattern to make it work

```
string pattern = "ABC...GHI"

code = "A"  //valid
code = "ABC" valid
code = "ABCDE" //valid
code = "ABCXXX" //valid
code = "ABCXXXGHI" //valid
code = "ABCXXXGHIAA" //invalid
code = "B" //invalid

Regex.IsMatch(code, pattern)
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Please explain the logic. Why is `ABCDE` valid, but `ABCXXXGHIAA` not valid? Shouldn't `ABCXXXGHIAA` match `ABC`? Is `ABxyzzy999` valid? Or are you saying that valid strings can't be longer than, in this case, 9 characters, and all of the characters in the string must match the pattern?

Comment: Yes the strings cant be longer than the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?` and make optional part of regexp. The final regexp string could be

```
A(B(C(.(.(.(G(H(I?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

The final string is quite messy but you can create it automatically

The visualization of above regexp is here http://www.regexper.com/#A(B(C(.(.(.(G(H(I%3F)%3F)%3F)%3F)%3F)%3F)%3F)%3F)%3F

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var pat = new Regex(@"^A(B(C(.(Z)?)?)?)?");
var testStrings = new string[]
{
    "ALPHA",
    "ABGOOF",
    "ABCblah",
    "ABCbZ",
    "FOOBAR"
};
foreach (var s in testStrings)
{
    var m = pat.Match(s);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} matches {1}", s, m.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No match found for {0}", s);
    }
}
```

Results from that are:

```
ALPHA matches A
ABGOOF matches AB
ABCblah matches ABCb
ABCbZ matches ABCbZ
No match found for FOOBAR
```

The key is that everything after the A is optional. So if you wanted strings that start with A or AB, you'd have:

```
AB?
```

If you wanted to add ABC, you need:

```
A(BC?)?
```

Another character:

```
A(B(CZ?)?)?
```

Messy, but you could write code to generate the expression automatically if you had to.

### Additional info

It's possible that you want the strings to be no longer than the pattern, and all characters must match the pattern. That is, given the pattern I showed above, "ABCxZ" would be valid, but "ABCblah" would not be valid because the "lab" part doesn't match the pattern. If that's the case, then you need to add a "$" to the end of the pattern to say that the string ends there. So:

```
var pat = new Regex(@"^A(B(C(.(Z)?)?)?)?$");
```

Or, in your example case:

```
"^A(B(C(.(.(.(G(H(I)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$"
```

Comment: Hi Jim its actually the other way round
A matches Alpha
AB matches ABGOOF
ABCb matches ABCblah

Comment: Actually, the string `"ABGOOF"` matches the pattern `"^AB"`. The terminology I'm most familiar with says, "The string matches the pattern," rather than, "The pattern matches the string." But if you want to look at it the other way, fine with me.